# Yocto using OpenCV

Tags: opencv, yocto

experts,

I am building an Linux image, where i have an application that is using OpenCV. I receive an error that i cannot solve.
It seems that a i need to set a system variable. But which path to use?

```
By not providing "FindOpenCV.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "OpenCV", but
 CMake did not find one.

Could not find a package configuration file provided by "OpenCV" with any
of the following names:

     OpenCVConfig.cmake
     opencv-config.cmake

   Add the installation prefix of "OpenCV" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
   "OpenCV_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "OpenCV"
   provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
   installed.


 -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

Comment: Please share your application recipe and mention the versions for yocto and the layer you get opencv from.

Comment: thanks for the feedback. I expected to be an easy solution, e.g. missing env. variable.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. i missed to add following to the yocto-recipe:
DEPENDS = "opencv"